# HIghlighting row during runtime

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to highlight a row based user input. I am using Angular 5, with ag-grid-angular 19.1.2.  Setting the style with gridOptions.getRowStyle changes the background, but I would rather use scss classes if possible. The function setHighlight() is called in the *html* file through (change)=setHighlight()

```
setHighlight() {
const nextChronoId = this.getNextChronoDateId();
// this.highlightWithStyle(nextChronoId); // Working solution
this.highlightWithClass(nextChronoId);
const row = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(nextChronoId);
this.gridApi.redrawRows({ rowNodes: [row]})
}
```

Function definitions:

```
  highlightWithStyle(id: number) {
  this.gridApi.gridCore.gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
  if (params.data.Id === id) {
    return { background: 'green' }
   }
  }
 }

highlightWithClass(id: number) {
this.gridApi.gridCore.gridOptions.getRowClass = function(params) {
  if (params.data.Id === id) {
    return 'highlighted'
  }
 }
}
```

My scss class:

```
/deep/ .ag-theme-balham .ag-row .ag-row-no-focus .ag-row-even .ag-row-level0 .ag-row-last, .highlighted{
 background-color: green;
}
```

**My issue**
Using getRowClass does not apply my *highlighted* class correctly to the rowNode. After reading (and trying) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173268/css-classes-not-picked-up-during-angular-5-compilation), I think that my custom scss class overwritten by the ag-classes. The same problem occurs when using *rowClassRules*.

**Question**
How can I make Angular 5 and ag-grid work together in setting my custom scss class correctly?

Stepping with the debugger shows the class is picked up and appended to the native ag-grid classes.

In *rowComp.js*: [image]

Addition, screen dump from dev tools:
[image: Screen dump]

Comment: just for testing: Is it applied correctly if you add `!important` to your css definition.
Also `/deep/` is deprecated

Comment: Removing /deep/ and adding !important did not fix the issue.

Comment: is your class added to the DOM and can you see in the browsers dev tools that it is present but overwritten?

Comment: It is visible when I mouse over in dev tools, but I can not view the class under the styles pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular's `ViewEncapsulation`is the culprit here.

First be aware that all shadow piercing selectors like `/deep/` or `::ng-deep` are or will be deprecated.

this leaves, to my knowledge, two options.

- use `ViewEncapsulation.None`
- add your `highlighted` class to the global stylesheet

setting `ViewEncapsulation.None` brings its own possible problems:
All components styles would become globally available styles.

I would advise to go with option two.

[this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52848464/885338) sums it up pretty well.

Additionally:
`.ag-theme-balham .ag-row .ag-row-no-focus .ag-row-even .ag-row-level0 .ag-row-last`
this selector will never match anything, you should change it to

`.ag-theme-balham .ag-row.ag-row-no-focus.ag-row-even.ag-row-level0.ag-row-last`

every class after `ag-theme-balham` exists on the same element.
with the selector you wrote, you would denote a hierarchy.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, I also had to remove .ag-theme-balham .ag-row.ag-row-no-focus.ag-row-even.ag-row-level0.ag-row-last, keeping only .highlighted { ... }